# Dictionary entry to file fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am having a requirement of downloading certain libraries from the repository. I use the get method from Requests module to achieve that. However, on every run of the code, the libraries are fetched over and over again. So we plan to optimise it in the following way:

For all the libraries downloaded, we create a dictionary entry on a text file as follows:

```
download_libs()
add_entry_to_text_file(name,version, directory)
```

The `add_entry_to_text_file(name,version, directory)`  is defined as below:

```
    details = {'name': name,
              'asked_version': version}
    with open(directory + '\\filename.txt', 'a') as f:
        for key, value in details.items():
            f.write('%s:%s\t' % (key, value))
        f.write('\n')
```

After the first run, the txt file looks like below:

```
name:lib1   asked_version:11.12
name:lib2   asked_version:11.12
name:lib3   asked_version:11.14
name:lib4   asked_version:11.13
name:lib5   asked_version:11.15
```

Now, I run into a scenario of updating maybe lib4 to a new version of 11.20
I run the file again, and the library is added as a new entry to the text file.

```
name:lib1   asked_version:11.12
name:lib2   asked_version:11.12
name:lib3   asked_version:11.14
name:lib4   asked_version:11.13
name:lib5   asked_version:11.15
name:lib4   asked_version:11.20
```

I was under the impression that since I am entering a dictionary into the file, the new value for the library would just get updated in the text file rather than creating a whole new entry.

Should it be the case that the additional logic needs to be added before writing to a file, and not expecting dictionary to do it by default?

Comment: You should use json for this. The `dict` doesn't know anything about your file. You are manually extracting the `dict` and saving the results. You have to do all of the data management manually, with this method.

Comment: Look into using lightweight file database like SQLite and don't reinvent the wheel. As for your issue - you are appending to file, you need to read contents, process and then rewrite them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue comes from using `a` (append mode) in your `open` call. This means every time this function is called, a new line is added to the end and the file is never truncated.

If you open the file with `w` (write mode) the file will be truncated first, however you'll need to redesign your code to allow for this, otherwise you'll only have the most recently added entry.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you do not parse the file as a dictonary or at all.
What I would do is to first parse the file into a `dict` by running something like:

```
libs = {}
with open('path\\to\\file', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        tab_split = line.split()
        name = tab_split[0].split(':')[1]
        version = tab_split[1].split(':')[1]
        libs[name] = version
```

And before downloading a package I would check if that package name exists in `libs` as a key and if so if the version is higher than `libs[package_name]` and if so then update it and set `libs[package_name] = new_version`

At the end of the program you will need however to rewrite the file with the `libs` dict. You could run:

```
with open('path\\to\\file', 'w') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    for key in libs.keys():
        file.writelines(f"name:{key}\tversion:{libs[key]}\n")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The text file that's being produced is acting as an audit log rather than "dictionary" containing the latest version.

That's not necessarily the wrong behaviour – it can be useful to have the historical data, and it will reflect the actual files that have already been downloaded to local storage.

If the requirement were to only store the *latest* version then you're right – the logic would need to be updated to identify and rewrite existing entries. In this case, you would no longer be able to simply append the new entry – you'd have to read in all the existing entries, update the changed entry, and write everything back out as in [Noft's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787808/21146235).